# How to release windows application in vs team service?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-devops, windows, continuous-deployment

Hi buddy,
                I am new for team service.I have created a sample windows application then build and release into team services. But I don't know how to release my application through ftp?or any other ways to deploy windows application ...suggest me....
Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can add related tasks to deploy your windows to where you want to deploy.

Such as if you want to deploy your app to another machine, you can use [**Windows Machine File Copy** task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) .

More detail, you can refer [deploy your app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/).

Comment: thanks for your answer..@marina.i try ths only for ftp.but i got a error whle deploying..."System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Copying failed for resource :xxxxxxxxxx" on run by agent.i dont know .how to reslove this...

Comment: You can run windows Machine File copy task on a private agent instead. Or you can give your detail release definition log here in order to trouble shooting your issue.

Comment: Did you use the Windows Machine File copy task to deploy your app successfully?